# What was the Resistance's original plan for the siege cannon in The Last Jedi?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi

When the Resistance set out towards the [siege cannon](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Superlaser_siege_cannon) on their [V-4X-D](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/V-4X-D_ski_speeder) speeders, what did they hope to achieve? Was it a kamikaze run from the beginning, something that Finn tried to finish before Rose stopped him? Were the speeders packed with explosives? Or did they plan to use some other weapon and tactic?

**EDIT** For those doubting, Finn  really was only few seconds away from hitting the siege cannon, before Rose intervened . Finn was not the best pilot, but even he managed to get close to the cannon, so a suicide run was definitely possible. Would the speeder crashing into the siege cannon do some substantial damage - that is open to interpretation. In our world it would, but SW physics is different.

Comment: It was a delaying tactic to allow their allies to arrive. I don't think the plan was more complicated than "*there's the enemy, let's go kill them"*

Comment: You did notice that Finn never was going to get close enough, yes? Nor could the others. Without Luke, there'd have been no point.

Comment: They didn't know that to begin with, though.  Not for certain.

Comment: @Adamant - Don't you know? *Rebellions are built on hope*

Comment: There was a moment during Finn's attack run where they showed his speeder's cannons melting away. I think the original idea was probably to shoot the cannon, but since Finn was stupid and drove into the beam too early that stopped being an option.

Comment: @Valorum I'm not sure what are you implying, that they originally planned to attack walkers, presumably with cannons ? If you have time, please write an answer.

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh Could be, but siege cannon appears bigger then walkers, would cannons do any damage ?

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh - Exactly. Star Wars shows us *one* time when a suicide run *isn't* the best option (you know, like a lot of times in Real Life) and people can't believe it.

Comment: @Valorum - Exactly. And the opposite of hope is despair, e.g. suicide. Hope is *not* giving up, and *not* pointlessly killing oneself.

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh - And I really do mean just *one*. There were *three* suicidal heroic sacrifices in the movie, but people focus on the one where self-sacrifice was a bad idea

Comment: @HarryJohnston - *Two* highly qualified individuals, Poe and Rose, thought that it was pointless. Not to mention Leia etc., who would certainly have considered a run if they thought it would work. We're literally talking about the *one* scene where it's *not* a good idea to fly an almost unshielded craft into a miniature Death Star beam. One of the major themes of the film is the distinction between well-considered sacrifices (Holdo, Luke, Paige) and ill-considered sacrifices (Finn, Rey).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78665/discussion-between-adamant-and-rs-29).

Comment: @rs.29 - Instead of making innuendos about people's weight and appearance, why not consider that Poe, Rose, and Leia may actually have known what they were doing when they concluded that jumping right into the path of a Death Star reactor that could blow open a cliff face might not have been an effective strategy?

Comment: The real question, I think, is how Rose got to Finn before Finn got to the cannon. Her skiff must be a lot faster.

Comment: @ifly6 - Finn was flying against that cannon, which likely slowed him down. It likely would have gotten harder the closer he got to the source of the beam (another reason it wouldn't have worked, btw).

Comment: @rs.29 - I'm editing out the aside about Rose. It doesn't add to the question, and it's Not Nice.

Comment: @Adamant I see you do not like Rose :P But you also do not like physics, Finn was actually very close , almost at the mouth of cannon when ample flower :D crashed into him . 3:48 in the clip .

Comment: @ifly6 Finn has problems with his speeder throughout the flight. Either his crate does not work properly or he is not best of pilots.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The goal was to prevent the siege cannon from coming into range by destroying the tug walkers or the cables connecting the tugs to the siege cannon.

> *“Our objective is that cannon,” Leia said. “It’s the only thing that
> can crack our front door, so let’s try not to let it get in range.
> It’s being towed by tug walkers—squat, ugly, lots of legs. **If we take
> the tugs out, the cannon stops. If we break the cables they’re using
> to pull it, the cannon stops.”***
>
> <sub><sup>[The Last Jedi: Official Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Last_Jedi:_Expanded_Edition)</sup></sub>

Unfortunately (and unknown to the Resistance) this plan was doomed to failure from the start.

[image]
<sub><sup>[**The Last Jedi: Incredible Cross Sections**](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Last_Jedi:_Incredible_Cross-Sections)</sup></sub>

Comment: Sounds like usual incompetence from Resistance's leadership. But +1 for you, and if someone doesn't come up with  better answer I'm going to accept this.

Comment: Not sure it's really incompetence - it's literally a last-ditch effort that they likely know will fail, but the alternative is doing nothing and dying inside the bunker anyway. Realistically, even if they break the cables, they likely only buy a small amount of time until fresh cables are hooked up, but they're out of options.